# Resource Bundle MissingResourceException

Tags: java, resourcebundle

I'm trying to add an option to change the language in the program, the problem is that I can't find proper path to use and all the time i got a

> java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base nameMenuFactory_pl.properties, locale pl

```
            Locale locale =new Locale("pl");
            ResourceBundle myResources = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MenuFactory_pl.properties",locale);
```

I've tried adding the path of the package, and copy resource bundle to created pacakge java/resource and still i get an error.

[PIC WITH MORE INFO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7kvR.png)

Comment: In future, please avoid including screenshot of your code, rather paste the actual code, properly formatted, so that it is easier for the community members to check the code out and assist. Also include the complete error log.

Comment: Did any of answers help you? / solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.horstmann.violet.application.MenuFactory",locale)
```

or

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("com/horstmann/violet/application/MenuFactory",locale)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you specify bundle in an incorrect way. There should be no suffix _pl as it should be automatically added from your locale. Similarly there should be no .properties extension. this is the format to be followed (from a tutorial given below):

```
ResourceBundle labels = ResourceBundle.getBundle("LabelsBundle", currentLocale);
```

See more info on Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/propfile.html

**So to change your language you need to change Locale ie:**

```
Locale locale = new Locale("pl");
myResources = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MenuFactory",locale);
```

More on locale and i18n here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html

Pozdrowienia